# CS50 Pset1 cash code not working properly

Tags: c, cs50, greedy

So I just started with the cs50 course and I'm doing the 1 problem set with greedy algorithms. When I run the program it will ask the question right, when I answer it doesn't give output. I can't tell what's wrong.
Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)

{

float n;
int cents;
int coins = 0;

// Prompt user for amount owed
     do
     {
        n = get_float("Change owed?:");
     }
     while (n < 0);

// convert input into cents
     cents = round(n * 100);

//loop for minimum coins
    while (cents >= 25)
{
    cents = cents - 25;
    coins++;
}
    while (cents >= 10)
{
    cents = cents - 10;
    coins++;
}
    while (cents >= 5)
{
    cents = cents - 5;
    coins++;
}
    while (cents >= 1)
{
    cents = cents - 1;
    coins++;
//Print number of coins
printf("%i\n", coins);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your print method inside a while-loop, which if its condition evaluates to false, won't execute its body.

What happened is that nothing would get printed, unless `cents` would be greater or equal to 1 when reaching your last while-loop.

Change this:

```
while (cents >= 1)
{
    cents = cents - 1;
    coins++;
    //Print number of coins
    printf("%i\n", coins);
}
```

to this:

```
while (cents >= 1)
{
    cents = cents - 1;
    coins++;
}
//Print number of coins
printf("%i\n", coins);
```

With this change, the print method will execute, regardless of whether the code flow enters the last while-loop or not.